# c# xml deserialization using DataContractSerializer with unknown format

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have XML that contains statistic data, it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<response>
<responsecode>0</responsecode>
<count>2</count>
-<statistics>
<id>id</id>
<msisdn>somemsisdn</msisdn>
</statistics>
-<statistics>
<id>otherid</id>
<msisdn>othermsisdn</msisdn>
</statistics>
</response>
```

I try to deserialize it, but if there are more than two records - more elements will be added, and looks like they cannot be deserialized in some kind of list or array, i.e. i don't know exact format of XML.

Here is my code:

```
 [DataContract(Name = "response", Namespace = "")]
    class XMLStat
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 0)]
        public int responsecode;
        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public int count;
        [DataMember(Order = 2)]
        public List<StatElement> statistics;
        //public XMLStat() { statistics = new List<StatElement>(); }
    }

    [CollectionDataContract(ItemName="statistics", Namespace="")]
    class StatElement
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 0)]
        public string id;
        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public string msisdn;
    }

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(someurl);
            string result = string.Empty;
            DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(XMLStat));
            XMLStat stat = new XMLStat();
            using (var s = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
                stat = (XMLStat)ser.ReadObject(s);
```

It serializes responsecode and count, but list is empty. Am i right in my assumption that this is not a list(and is there any workaround), or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: I think you need `[XmlArray]` and
`[XmlArrayItem]` attributes for the `List`

Comment: @MikeDebela, it doesn't seem to work. I tried this:

`class XMLStat
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 0)]
        public int responsecode;
        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public int count;
        [XmlArray(Order=2, ElementName="statistics")]
        public List<StatElement> statistics;
    }

    [DataContract(Name="statistics")]
    class StatElement
    {
        [XmlArrayItem]
        public string id;
        [XmlArrayItem]
        public string msisdn;
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `XmlSerializer`, this will successfully deserialize the input:

Assuming you have this input xml:

```
string xmlText = "<?xml version='1.0'?> " +
  "<response>" +
    "<responsecode>0</responsecode>" +
    "<count>2</count>" +
    "<statistics>" +
       "<id>id</id>" +
       "<msisdn>somemsisdn</msisdn>" +
    "</statistics>" +
    "<statistics>" +
       "<id>otherid</id>" +
       "<msisdn>othermsisdn</msisdn> " +
    "</statistics>" +
  "</response> ";
```

And your classes:

```
  [XmlRoot("response")]
  public class XMLStat
  {
    public int responsecode;
    public int count;
    [XmlElement("statistics")]
    public List<StatElement> statistics;
  }

  public class StatElement
  {
    public string id;
    public string msisdn;
  }
```

Then the deserialization:

```
XMLStat obj = new XMLStat();
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XMLStat));
using (var strReader = new StringReader(xmlText))
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(strReader))
{
     obj = (XMLStat)ser.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Comment: looks like it works. I didn't post the whole xml(it has some other fields), now it gives me error in this element:
<load_date>2016-04-27 15:42:50</load_date> , exception is:
There is an error in XML document (13, 43).
13,43 is the end of this attribute, so i have no idea how can it be error there. 
Anyway, thanks, at least now it tries to serialize statistics)